# add double quotes to c:set or ArrayList

Tags: javascript, java

Struggling with what is probably simple code to append double quotes to each element either in the c:set or in the ArrayList or in the JavaScript variable.

After a c:set (which contains mother, baby etc) I populate an ArrayList (which then contains [mother, baby, child, staff] etc) and then 'get it' into JavaScript.

The final output is [mother, child, staff] etc but I need it to be ["mother", "baby", "child", "staff"] etc

```
After a sql:select - 
<c:set var="type" value="${row.Type}"  />

Add to an ArrayList -
       types.add(pageContext.getAttribute("type"));

Get into javascript (after the jstl forEach loop completes)-

var typesArray = [<% for (int i = 0; i < types.size(); i++) { %>"<%=types.get(i)%>"<%= i + 1 < types.size() ? ",":"" %><% } %>];
```

Can't add double quotes to the c:set because it then escapes / fails -

```
<c:set var="type" value=""${row.Type}""  />
```

I don't really want to use StringBuffer because that affects the JavaScript get iterator which took me days to get working.

Assume old Java / old Javascript

Thoughts appreciated.
Regards. Ralph

Comment: Without reading or understanding the entire problem, the first think I'd try is to combine the `'` and `"` characters, resulting in `"'${row.Type}'"`.

Comment: Thanks but that (which I use in another part of my code) adds a single quote / apostrophe around each element and I need double quotes. I would be happy if I could somehow add double quotes to the c:set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single / double quote wrapping ,

```
<c:set var="type" value="'${row.Type}'"  />
```

or

```
<c:set var="type" value='"${row.Type}"'  />
```

Similarly ,

```
var typesArray = [<% for (int i = 0; i < types.size(); i++) { %>"'<%=types.get(i)%>'"<%= i + 1 < types.size() ? ",":"" %><% } %>];
```

or

```
var typesArray = [<% for (int i = 0; i < types.size(); i++) { %>'"<%=types.get(i)%>"' <%= i + 1 < types.size() ? ",":"" %><% } %>];
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed the array but broke the get into Javascript, maybe it is better to do any conversion after the get?

Comment: Added. Check it is helpful

Comment: You are a lifesaver, fixed the typesArray (chart.js tooltips into which typesArray feeds is broken but that's another story for later).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
<c:set var="type" value="\"${row.Type}\""  />
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed the c:set and array but broke the get into Javascript, maybe it is better to do any conversion after the get?

Comment: Maybe the use [backticks of the ES2015 specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can help you, take a look.